# How does the presence of "log n" with "n", affect this? As there is another function multiplied

Tags: recursion, recurrence

*T(n)= 4T(n/3)+(n^2)logn*
Can I use master theorem in this?
The answer I got was (n^2)logn which my teacher said was wrong. So, kindly help I'm stuck. :/

Comment: You can indeed use the Master Theorem. Can you explain how you got `n log n`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant n^2 logn.

Comment: And how did you obtain this answer? Which case of the Master Theorem do you think applies, and why?

Comment: I actually used master theorem and reached this answer, cuz (log4 base 3) is smaller than 2 (from n^2) therefore answer would be f(n) which is n^2 logn. How is it wrong?

Comment: It's I guess case 2, which says if f(n)> g(n). Then O(f(n)). Here f(n) = n^2 logn and g(n)= n^(log4 base 3).

Comment: `n^2 log n` is correct (however that would be [Case 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form)). Discuss with your teacher, and also check whether you copied the question correctly (was it e.g. `T(n/2)`?).